# Необходимо, чтобы сервопривод MG995 вращался в определенное время на 90 градусов и в определенное время обратно

Tags: arduino

Вот код, но на часы реального времени (DS1307) сервопривод не обращает внимание и не вращается. Что в нем исправить или переписать как-то код?

```
#include <TroykaRTC.h> 
#include <iarduino_RTC.h> 
#include <Servo.h> 
// библиотека для работы I?C 
#include <Wire.h> 
// библиотека для работы с часами реального времени 
#include "TroykaRTC.h" 

// размер массива для времени 
#define LEN_TIME 12 
// размер массива для даты 
#define LEN_DATE 12 
// размер массива для дня недели 
#define LEN_DOW 12 

// создаём объект для работы с часами реального времени 
RTC clock; 

Servo servo; 
// массив для хранения текущего времени 
char time[LEN_TIME]; 
// массив для хранения текущей даты 
char date[LEN_DATE]; 
// массив для хранения текущего дня недели 
char weekDay[LEN_DOW]; 

void setup() 
{ 
// открываем последовательный порт 
Serial.begin(9600); 
// инициализация часов 
clock.begin(); 
// метод установки времени и даты в модуль вручную 
//clock.set(10,25,45,27,07,2005,THURSDAY); 
// метод установки времени и даты автоматически при компиляции 
clock.set(__TIMESTAMP__); 
// что бы время менялось при прошивки или сбросе питания 
// закоментируйте оба метода clock.set(); 
servo.attach(5); // Указываем объекту класса Servo, что серво присоединен к пину 9 
servo.write(0); // Выставляем начальное положение 
} 

void loop() 
{ 
// запрашиваем данные с часов 
clock.read(); 
// сохраняем текущее время, дату и день недели в переменные 
clock.getTimeStamp(time, date, weekDay); 
// выводим в serial порт текущее время, дату и день недели 
Serial.print(time); 
Serial.print("\t"); 
Serial.print(date); 
Serial.print("\t"); 
Serial.println(weekDay); 

//здесь надо будет написать условие, когда должен открываться и закрываться серво, к примеру if(такое-то время) и в фигурные скобки взять 3 строчки про поворот, ожидание и поворот обратно 
if (time=="14:12:00") 
//{ 
servo.write(0); 
delay(1000); 
servo.write(90); 
if (time=="14:13:00") 

servo.write(180); 
delay(1000); 


//} 
// ждём одну секунду 
//} 
delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: 1) операторные скобки после if

Comment: 2) условие `time=="14:12:00"` сравнивает не значения строк, а адреса. Они константные и всегда не равны. Используйте `strcmp` или замените одну из строк на класс String

Comment: Не сильно соображаем, не могли ли вы это сделать, пожалуйста

Comment: if((time[0]==1) && (time[1]==1) && (time[3]==0) && (time[4]==0) && (time[6]==0) && (time[7]==0))
{
servo.write(0);
delay(1000);
servo.write(90);
}
if((time[0]==1) && (time[1]==1) && (time[3]==0) && (time[4]==1) && (time[6]==0) && (time[7]==0))
{
servo.write(180);
delay(1000);
servo.write(90);
}
delay(1000);
}

Comment: такой код тоже не срабатывет

Comment: Оберните цифры в одинарные кавычки. Вы сейчас сравниваете не с символом, а с его ASCII-кодом.

Comment: if((time[0]=='1') && (time[1]=='1') && (time[3]=='0') && (time[4]=='0') && (time[6]=='0') && (time[7]=='0'))